# Stop Slide Show on mouse over in Javascript

Tags: javascript, slide

I am using following java-script for a slide show, now I like to pause the loop on mouse-over event on the element "dot", my expertise in java is zero, please help.

```js
 <script>
    var slideIndex = 0;
    showSlides();

    function showSlides() {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
           slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        slideIndex++;
        if (slideIndex > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
           dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active","");
        }
        slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
        setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change text every 5 seconds
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onmouseover stop slideshow help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053770/onmouseover-stop-slideshow-help)

Comment: it would really help if you provide your `HTML` code.

Answer (score 1):

A few things. Firstly, I would suggest using `setInterval()` instead. This allows you to easily stop the timer outside of the function. The syntax is identical to `setTimeout()`. `setInterval()` is very similar to `setTimeout()`, except it will continue to execute the function (the first parameter) until you call `clearInterval()`.

Note that `setInterval()` (and `setTimeout()`) returns a value, which can be used for `clearInterval()` and `clearTimeout()`, respectively.

Changing your code to utilize setInterval should be fairly straightforward. Given what you have posted above, it might look something like this:

```
<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
       dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active","");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
var interval = setInterval(showSlides, 5000); // Change text every 5 seconds
```

Note that I save `interval` as a variable that can be used later to stop the timer.

Once you have made this change, the solution to your main question becomes much easier. You can set up event handlers by adding the following:

```
function pauseSlides(event)
{
    clearInterval(interval); // Clear the interval we set earlier
}
function resumeSlides(event)
{
    interval = setInterval(showSlides, 5000);
}
// Set up event listeners for the dots
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
   dots[i].onmouseover = pauseSlides;
   dots[i].onmouseout = resumeSlides;
}
```

The entirety of your code, given the above, may now look something like this:

```
<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
       dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active","");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
var interval = setInterval(showSlides, 5000); // Change text every 5 seconds

// Set up event listeners for the dots
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
   dots[i].onmouseover = pauseSlides;
   dots[i].onmouseout = resumeSlides;
}

function pauseSlides()
{
    clearInterval(interval); // Clear the interval we set earlier
}
function resumeSlides()
{
    interval = setInterval(showSlides, 5000);
}
</script>
```

Additionally, for reference:

setInterval() reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Events in JavaScript: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

Answer (score 0):

Wonderful Aaron, much appreciated response. I just checked the code and its working perfectly.

Can we modify this code further and on-mouse over event we can go to specific slide? i mean by using the same "dot" element? The dots are representing different slides, so I want if a user trigger mouse over event on any dot, the slide display benith that specific dot element.